# What's the equivalent to densha, futsuu, tokkyuu, and kyuukou in the West?

Tags: words

I know that they are all trains, but what would their counterparts be in the US or even Western Europe? Or better yet, when do you use one train as opposed to the other?

Comment: It seems a bit of a false comparison to try to align a single transit system (or single set of systems) against the rest of the world's...

Comment: Is it on topic to ask Japanese to English questions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a cultural comparison, not directly about any facet of the Japanese language.

Comment: @istrasci I just understood the question to be "What's the difference between 急行, 特急, etc. when referring to trains?"

Comment: They aren't even consistent within Japan (the following are all Osaka lines). Hankyu/Keihan/Kintetsu/Hanshin use 普通・準急・急行・快速急行・特急 with minor variations. JR uses 普通・快速・新快速・特急. And the 特急 on JR is very different from that of private railways. I'm sure there are many regional differences too.

Comment: @jmac:  You forgot the _K_ 特急 on the Keihan line!  Also, +1 for Osaka!

Comment: @istrasci I left out most of the odd trains that are infrequent (like the 通勤特急, etc.). Perhaps I should ask what the equivalent to Japanese 小・中・大 for drink sizes is in the West?

Comment: I don't see why this question should be put on hold. I have often tried to make sense of how these trains were named. An explanation would be an insight into how these words/characters are used in general. (See my previous comment on use of 特　ーit might be dumb but there is nothing  wrong with dumb questions if they are genuine; is'nt that what this site is for?)

Comment: @Tim:  See my comment above for why I voted to close.  Because it is about a cultural comparison.  If the question is edited to focus more on the meanings of the individual types, I'll vote to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

電車 【でんしゃ】 (densha) is an electric train, because 電 refers to electric.

普通 【ふつう】 (futsuu) is a local train, one that stops at every station.

特急 【とっきゅう】 (tokkyuu) is an express or limited stop train. These usually only stop at main stations to reduce the travel time. 急 refers to the speed such as rapid or fast.

急行 【きゅうこう】 (kyuukou) is a high speed train, relatively speaking, in any area. Refers to the speed of the train, not necessarily the transit time. Rough interpretation of the  kanji would mean something like "moves fast".

I doubt these types are specific to any country, to the extent such services are available.

Comment: But for train lines in Japan, a 急行 usually refers to a limited stop train, which (in the case of the 井の頭線, for example) might only be 5 minutes faster over a local train, which takes 31 minutes... It doesn't necessarily travel any faster than the local train.

Comment: @Earthling It sounds like, according to your description, there's no difference between a 特急 and a 急行. They seem to do the same thing.

Comment: @dotnetN00b A (準)特急 is usually stops at even less stations than a regular 急行. I was only nitpicking with the description "high-speed train", because the 急行 doesn't necessarily drive at a faster speed than a local train.

Comment: I recently noticed that 特く　can meant special in the sense of limited. My example is a bit esoteric but if a bank becomes a member of the Japan Securities Dealers Association then it is a 特定会員 rather than a 会員、as would be normal for a securities co. Has anybody else noticed other similar cases to this other than naming of train expresses?

Answer (score 3):

Because "in the West" is quite general, I'll just draw a parallel with Germany. In Germany, the national rail network has similarities to the system in Tokyo.

On a regional level there are the

- [RB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regionalbahn) (*Regionalbahn* "regional train"), which stops at any town with a train station
- [RE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional-Express) (*Regional-Express* "regional express"), which leaves out the smallest stations

Between regions there is the

- [IRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interregio-Express) (*Interregional-Express*), which connects bordering regions and stops at large towns or cities

National trains are

- [IC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercity_%28Deutsche_Bahn%29) (*Intercity*), which stops only at cities
- [ICE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercity-Express) (*Intercity Express*) which stops only at the bigger cities

They compare to the trains in Tokyo as follows

- RB = 各駅停車, 普通
- RE = (通勤)快速
- IRE = 急行
- IC = 準特急
- ICE = 特急

And, of course, 電車 just means "train" and not any particular type of railway.